# Disabling Replication and Replicated Tables

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional-replication

I have transactional replication set up between Database1 and Database2 using SQL Server 2017. About 20 tables are being replicated to Database2, a few of them are pretty large. I would like to disable replication but at the same time I would like to keep all the data being replicated to DB2 as well as the keys etc. In short, when I turn off replication I don't want to loose any of the replicated data.

Any recommendations?

Comment: I don't fully understand the question. Are you trying to temporarily or permanently disable replication? Dropping replication doesn't remove the previously synchronized objects and data from the Subscriber databases.

Comment: Yes I am trying to permanently remove replication.

Comment: Disabling replication wouldn't affect existing data in subscribed database. Make sure you disabled coordinated backup (if it was enabled before) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/administration/enable-coordinated-backups-for-transactional-replication?view=sql-server-ver16